# How to delete Google AdSense account?

Tags: mobile, admob, adsense

I am trying to open up an AdMob account but I get this warning, I had made AdSense a few years ago but the site never really was in use.

You need a valid AdSense account to sign up with AdMob, but your AdSense account application is either disapproved or currently in review by AdSense.

I know I can just create a new google ID and use that to get AdMob, but why complicate things.

There must be a way to open up AdMob with my current account other than verifying AdSense.